# Adding screenshot to allure report

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress, allure

I have no idea how to add a screenshot to allure report. I can't find any example. I'm using cypress and mocha-allure-reporter. Report is genereting properly but have no idea how to setup it and add screenshots in my project

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin: https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin
Screenshots should be attached automatically